# How to add a new item in a drop down list of select component using reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-select

I have a dropdown component that uses the Select component from react-select dependency. I have added a button in the dropdown's option list and on click of this button, I need to enter some text and need to add the text in the dropdown's option list on pressing enter button. I tried to keep the initial option list in a state variable, and then update it, but it didn't work as expected. Here is my component:

```
    import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import Select from "react-select";
import { get } from "../../helpers";
const ReactSelect = props => {

    const { state, component, onChange, disabled = false } = props;
    let showError = false;
    const {
        name,
        placeholder,
        optionConfig = false,
        optionList = [],
        className,
        maxItems = null
        
    } = component;
    

 
  
  
    const newOptionList=[
        ...optionList,
        {label: (
            <>
                <hr />
                <button
                    className="btn btn-icon" >
                    <cds-icon shape="plus"></cds-icon>ADD TYPE
                </button>
            </>
        ),
        value: "Add Type"}
    ];
    const options = !!optionConfig ? get(state, `${optionConfig}`, []) : newOptionList;
    
    const getSelectValue = () => {
        const selectedList = get(state, `${name}`, []);
        const selectedSet = new Set(selectedList);
        return options.filter(item => selectedSet.has(item.value));
    };

    const handleOnChange = selectedOption => {
        console.log(selectedOption);
        if(selectedOption.value !== "Add Type"){
            console.log(selectedOption);
            onChange({ value: selectedOption, component });
        } else {
            console.log("button selected");
            onChange({ value: selectedOption, component });
        }
    };

    
   

    const defaultSelectProps = {
        value: getSelectValue(),
        name: "category",
        options,
        menuPosition: "absolute",
        isDisabled: disabled,
        placeholder
    };

    return (
        <div  key={name}>
           
            <div className={`react-select-box ${className}`}>
                <Select
                    {...defaultSelectProps}
                   
                />
                {
                    showError &&
                    <span className="clr-subtext multiselect-error">
                        You can select upto {maxItems} items only.
                    </span>
                }
            </div>

        </div>

    );
};

ReactSelect.propTypes = {
    selectWithoutBox: PropTypes.bool
};

ReactSelect.defaultProps = {
    selectWithoutBox: false
};
export default ReactSelect;
```

Here, in the getSelectvalue function, I am returning the option selected by the user and it gets displayed.

Here is the get method:

```
export function get(source, path, defaultValue) {
if (typeof path === "number") {
    path = String(path);
}

if (path && source) {
    let parts = path.split(".");
    let length = parts.length;
    let result = source;

    for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        let item = result[parts[i]];

        if (item === null || item === undefined) {
            return item || defaultValue;
        }

        result = item;
    }

    return result;
}

return defaultValue;
```

}

Can anyone please tell me how can I add values in the option list here?

Comment: Well, please, post only the relevant code so we can focus on the issue.

Comment: Okay. I have edited the post and removed the irrrelevant code.

Comment: did you solved?